# Como validar um maskedtextbox em branco?

Tags: javascript, c#, textbox

No caso o `maskedtextboxTEL (00)0000-0000` devolveria um `error provider` e só prosseguiria após o preenchimento do mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `método` [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Código**

```
 if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_Telefone.Text))
 {
    errorProvider1.SetError(txt_Telefone, "Preencha o telefone ! ");
 }
```

Comment: Acho que não vai funcionar, se for uma mask, vai ter vim o .Text preenchido com (00) 0000-0000

Comment: hmm.. pior que e mesmo em ... acha devo manter a resposta ? afinal não deixa de estar validando um conteúdo em branco né .o pior que o autor da pergunta parece ter abandonado o site =´(. Eu levei em consideração mais pelo titulo da pergunta dele mesmo.

Comment: Vamos esperar pra ver o que o autor da pergunta falou.